# Mongo Query with $in array in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to create this query from `Java` for `MongoDB`. 
Do you know how can I construct it in java?

```
db.node.find({
 connectedWithIds: { $in: [ 
     ObjectId('56bca32fe74a987ad8724da1')       
     ] }
})
```

I tried to use this:

```
ObjectId arr[] = {new ObjectId("5409ae2e2cdc31c5aa0ce0a5")};
BasicDBObject inQuery = new BasicDBObject("$in", arr);
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("connectedWithIds", inQuery);
```

but the results is below:

```
{ "connectedWithIds" : { "$in" : [ { "$oid" : "5409ae2e2cdc31c5aa0ce0a5"}]}}
```

and occurs this error:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue cannot nest $ under $in",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could overcome this error with the code below:

```
    ArrayList<ObjectId> vals = new ArrayList<ObjectId>();
    vals.add(objectId);       
    BasicDBObject inQuery = new BasicDBObject("$in", vals);
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("connectedWithIds", inQuery);
    List<BasicDBObject> users = (List<BasicDBObject>) customQueryManager.executeQuery("node", query);
```